# wrong cv::putText results

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using openCV to draw some text over a frame (cv::Mat) with cv::putText.
However, the output displays `4?=` or `,?,` and such (change every run) instead of the `"Funny text inside the box"`.

My (Simplified) code:

```
Mat image = Mat::zeros(imgH,imgW, CV_8UC1);
int fontFace = FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL;
double fontScale = 1.5;
int thickness = 2;
Point textOrg(imgW/5, imgH/1.2);
string someText = "Funny text inside the box";
putText(image, someText, textOrg, fontFace, fontScale, Scalar::all(255), thickness, 8);
```

What could be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Unless that piece of code exhibits the symptoms, the problem is within "simplified".

Comment: This code generate the same results.

Comment: Used cvMat (and its components) and it's working.
Must have been some issues with the linking libraries.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're not doing anything else to the string ?
Your code seems to run just fine:

[image: cv::putText]

Here's the full code I ran:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    int imgW = 650;
    int imgH = 50;

    Mat image = Mat::zeros(imgH,imgW, CV_8UC1);
    int fontFace = FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL;
    double fontScale = 1.5;
    int thickness = 2;
    Point textOrg(imgW/5, imgH/1.2);
    string someText = "Funny text inside the box";
    putText(image, someText, textOrg, fontFace, fontScale, Scalar::all(255), thickness,8);

    for(;;){
        imshow("text",image);
        if(waitKey(30) > 0) break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Couldn't run the code.
However, I've changed my code to use cvMat, and it's worked, so for now I'm satisfied.
Thanks!

Comment: glad u sorted it out. strange behavour though, are eyou using the c or c++ api ?

Comment: used the c++, switched to c after this (still unidentified) problems.
My guess is that somewhere my compilation of the c++ libraries went wrong.

Comment: I have the same problem with OpenCV library version 2.4.9.0 rev 1 on my Note 3. The text shows a mixture of "?" and some random symbols. The same text shows correctly in LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

OK I struggled with the same problem and finally got it resolved for OpenCV library version 2.4.9.0 rev 1. The following specifics is for Android native activity but the general idea for any platform is the same.

For Android:
I first added "`OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC`" in **Android.mk** to try linking the library statically. The linker gave a bunch of error about - what else - std::string. Then I happened to notice that there was this line "`APP_STL := stlport_static`" in **Application.mk**. I don't know how it got there but I changed it to "`APP_STL := gnustl_static`" and everything worked.

In general: try linking to the OpenCV library statically to expose the error. Then you can track down and fix the mismatch in the include and the actual library used for STL.

I hope this helps someone else having the same issue.